# call function via include

Tags: php

how to include one page into another;

for example page 1 include page 2. page 2 does not show any content until it get the right arguments.

this is page 2 direct url call

```
www.mypage.com/execute.php?cmd=test
```

output is hello world

but when include the same page into page 1 like

```
include('execute.php?cmd=test');
```

or

```
$_GET['cmd']=$test;  
include('execute.php');
```

sorry but i think you guys didn't understand me quite right. what im trying to do is, page 2 have some content which must be displayed only when its needed so therefore is have created a function in page 2 so I can call it. the content of must be viewed on page 1 by call. so i have tried to do which normally works 'execute.php?cmd=test' but its not this time

Comment: The first syntax won't get you too far. The second will work, but you could also just set a variable directly and reference it in the execute.php, without using the $_GET public variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think I understand what you're trying to do, it is the wrong approach. Use a third PHP script that both your pages will include. This way, you won't have to hack the `$_GET` super global variable.

**includes/somescript.php**

```
// do something with $cmd
if ($cmd == 'test') echo 'Hello world';
```

**page1.php**

```
$cmd = 'test';
include 'includes/somescript.php';
```

**page2.php**

```
$cmd = $_GET['cmd'];
include 'includes/somescript.php';
```

Of course, the file `includes/somescript.php` should not just be executed like that, it should contain a `function` or a class with arguments that you include, then invoke from your pages. Up to you if you're going OO or procedural with this.

### Procedural

**includes/somescript.php**

```
function execute($cmd) {
   // ...
}
```

**page1.php**

```
include `includes/somescript.php';

execute('test');
```

### Object Oriented

**includes/somescript.php**

```
class CommandHandler {
    public function execute($cmd) {
        //...
    }
}
```

**page2.php**

```
include `includes/somescript.php';

$h = new CommandHandler();
$h->execute($_GET['cmd']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this:

```
$test = $_GET['cmd'];
```

That will work in both pages.